# Initial format of TimeInput

Tags: python, django

In my model `Event` I have a field with a date:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    start = models.DateTimeField()
```

Also, I use a custom widget for this field:

```
class SplitDateTime(forms.SplitDateTimeWidget):

    template_name = 'split_datetime.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            forms.SelectDateWidget,
            forms.TimeInput(
                attrs={'size': '5', 'placeholder': 'HH:MM', 'maxlength': '5'})
        )

        # Note that we're calling MultiWidget, not SplitDateTimeWidget, because
        # we want to define widgets.
        forms.MultiWidget.__init__(self, widgets, attrs)
```

My problem:

In my admin or in an `UpdateView`, the initial time is in the form of `HH:MM:SS`, but I'd prefer only `HH:MM`. Where should I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize this for all the inputs Date and DateTime by adding the TIME_INPUT_FORMATS into the settings.py

```
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%I:%M',    # '14:30'
]
```

[Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#date-input-formats)